# Include folder script

Tags: php, function

I want a function to execute php files in a particular directory may cuprinte subdirectories with separate scripts.

Example:

I have folder

> script

where is

> 1234.php

link'ul in this case to be

> www.mysite.com/test/1234

and

I have folder

> user

where is

> register.php

link'ul in this case to be

> www.mysite.com/user/register

I managed to do but it's something like index.php?page=script not want it ... how can I change out my function I described above?

my function is

```
> function loadcontent() {      include("config.php");  
>   if(isset($_GET['page']))    {       $page = replace($_GET['page']);
> 
>           include("module/".$page.".php");
>           if(!file_exists("module/".$page.".php"))        {           $error=1;           echo error("Script not exist.");
> 
>       }   }   else    {       if(isset($page) == NULL)        {           $page = 'acasa';
>           include("module/".$page.".php");        }   } }
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: What your question exactly?

Comment: I managed to do but it's something like index.php?page=script not want it ... how can I change out my function I described above? My function is

Answer (score 0):

You should read and learn about htaccess files and how to write them in order to rewrite your urls

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

And for the future, stackoverflow is about helping people debug/solve/find theyr problems in CODE, not just asking for a complete solution to an issue or implementation of a feature.

Comment: Functions does not exist?

Comment: No, you cannot rewrite urls with pure php functions. As I stated, htaccess is the answer for your needs.